# How to override the default style in element-plus

Tags: css, element-plus

When ever i use any element-plus component there is always a default style and color given to it.

for example

```
 <el-button type="primary">Primary</el-button>
```

it has a default color of blue. changing the color of a button is easy but there are some components that are quite difficult to change their styling

I'm trying to find the main file where I can change the styling to my linking.

when I use inspect on the browser it tells me the  index.css is in node-modules/element-plus/dist/index.css but when i navigate to the folder its not in there